# Is there any official confirmation that Denmark will replace their French 155mm guns (that they're giving to Ukraine) with Israeli ones?

Tags: military, israel, denmark

A couple of sources [1](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davidaxe/2023/01/23/nato-countries-are-giving-ukraine-hundreds-of-their-old-howitzers-and-replacing-them-with-south-koreas-excellent-k-9/) [2](https://mobile.twitter.com/HthHans/status/1616720870000435201) seem to indicate that Denmark is giving away all their CAESAR 155mm howitzers to Ukraine... and planning to get Israeli ATMOS howitzers as replacements. The first part of this seems quite settled, as it's been covered by multiple other [sources](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/denmark-send-artillery-ukraine-delaying-own-build-up-2023-01-19/) (also in [Danish](https://ekstrabladet.dk/nyheder/politik/danmark-sender-laenge-ventet-vaabensystem-til-ukraine/9596797)).

As for the chosen replacement, it doesn't sound totally implausible as ATMOS [was](https://www.israeldefense.co.il/en/node/27961) apparently a finalist in the previous round of Danish acquisitions, but I could find no official source to confirm this is the chosen replacement, but I can't really read Danish myself. So is this part confirmed in any official Danish sources?

As an aside, the [Twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/HthHans/status/1616720870000435201) source (it's a multi-Tweet "article", see parts 3-5) even claims ATMOS technically won the previous competition, but was then eliminated due to "political issues". Any truth to that part?

Comment: To me this looks more like a military question then a political one. Why not Israeli made weapons? Where is the political aspect of it?

Comment: they must have improved then... https://en.globes.co.il/en/article-elbit-atmos-artillery-performs-disappointingly-in-trial-1001203583

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: well, after reading the whole piece, it seems Israel did buy some in the end, so while the article is slamming the decision based on the earlier failures...

Comment: @ItalianPhilosophers4Monica: from a longer [piece](https://en.globes.co.il/en/article-idf-artillery-deal-no-tender-no-transparency-1001188602) in the same paper, it seems the Israeli decision was based on having 100% of production and IP in Israel. And Atmos was the only offer that met that requirement, so... Anyhow, that's not really relevant to my Q, although I suspect the initial Danish decision if it was "political" as some other source alleges, it might have been along those lines. E.g. Germany can't send EuroSpikes to Ukraine nowadays...

Comment: Best page for defence news in Denmark is thisone: https://olfi.dk/2023/01/23/politikere-maner-til-besindighed-inden-koeb-af-nyt-artilleri-til-erstatning-af-caesar/ It is behind paywall but the headline says: Politicians ask for sanity before purchase of new artillery to replace caesar. I also can't find twittersources etc. that say anything is confirmed.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle: thanks, otoh the same site also had a day before another article titled "Artilleriindkøbet begyndte med Atmos fra israelske Elbit, og det ender det også med" which in google translation reads "The artillery purchase began with Atmos from Israel's Elbit, and it also ends there". So the rumour is rather widespread.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle: OTOH I saw mentioned in the comments on those articles that Denmark also has EuroSpikes (in fact, this seems to be their only modern/current ATGM), and so the claim on political reservations regarding Israeli weapons might not be as strong as suggested in some other writeups.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is official now. Ministry of Defence just wrote that negotiations with Elbit Systems have started

[Ministry of Defense news](https://www.fmn.dk/da/nyheder/2023/bredt-flertal-enige-om-hurtig-genanskaffelse-af-artillerisystemer/)

For political context then the coorporation between Israel and Denmark have lately been interesting. During Covid there was a wierd alliance between Austria, Denmark and Israel that was questioned a lot (not that it is related in any way).